# Can T-SQL CREATE OR ALTER statements be run against production databases (without downtime)?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, ddl, transactional

We are imagining scenarios for rolling upgrades to our cloud environments and are imagining leveraging `CREATE OR ALTER` statements for our procedures, triggers, views and functions.

There is a gap between

```
DROP <OBJECT_CLASS> IF EXISTS <theThing> 
GO
```

and the eventual

```
CREATE <OBJECT_CLASS> <theNewThing>
GO
```

that will mean clients wont find the object, and in the case of triggers, the app may not even be able to detect an error. I am hoping that

```
CREATE OR ALTER <OBJECT_CLASS> <theOldOrNewThing>
```

can hopefully, maybe, provide a means to perform this otherwise non-transactional operation in the middle of transactions, perhaps locking out all new transactions until it is done (would that not be ideal!).

What are the risk or real-life experiences that you see?

Does anyone have authoritative technical insight into how SQL Server (2016 SP1+) will react to the `CREATE OR ALTER` statement on a running database?

Comment: Your question is too broad. DDL is could be perfectly fine in some of scenarios on production databases. Real question is what are those objects? Are they have locks for 24 hours in day or not. Note that there are exists metadata locks. So in general your question needs more info about objects/their sizes/client connections/acceptable offline delay. If you are interested I can try to expand comment to answer

Comment: It is important to note that CREATE OR ALTER exists only for PROCEDURES, FUNCTIONS, VIEWS and TRIGGERS. Traditionally these are items that are safe to CREATE only but not to DROP in case running code calls it directly or in the case of triggers, indirectly. 

The issue is attempting to do UPDATES on these objects. These objects themselves do not get locked in transactions, but they be used to generate result sets that are locked. Again, DDL statements are not transactional so they dont partake in locks, but databases maintain schemas which describing the DDL, and these can be locked.

Comment: Good point about transactions! **DDL statements are not transactional** - it's not so. I missed the point at which DDL in MSSQL became transactional too. I remember sometime in SQLServer 2008-2008/R2 I saw that DDL became transactional/partially transactional. And I can't find Microsoft documentation clearly describing limitations and possibilities of DDL in transactions. But don't blindly assume that all DDL operations are not transactional.

Comment: From [sp_settriggerorder  - General Trigger Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-settriggerorder-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#general-trigger-considerations): "If an **ALTER TRIGGER** statement changes a first or last trigger, the **First** or **Last** attribute originally set on the trigger is dropped, and the value is replaced by **None**. The order value must be reset by using **sp_settriggerorder**." It's a favorite bit of functionality.

Comment: Another option to consider - Aaron Bertrand's [Schema Switch-A-Roo](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2)

Comment: @ZoharPeled - interesting approach. I will play with it.